# Ionic typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to Ionic framework. I am trying out how to integrate fingerprint authorization within the application.

For that I have added in my `home.ts` file below code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { FingerprintAIO } from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fingerPrint: FingerprintAIO) {

  }

  this.fingerPrint.show({
    clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',
    clientSecret: 'password', //Only necessary for Android
    disableBackup:true,  //Only for Android(optional)
    localizedFallbackTitle: 'Use Pin', //Only for iOS
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate' //Only for iOS
  })
  .then((result: any) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
```

When I take an Android build using `ionic cordova build android`, I get the following error:

```
typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 16 
            Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. 

      L16:    this.fingerPrint.show({
      L17:      clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',

[15:24:38]  typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 25 
            Declaration or statement expected. 

      L24:    .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));

Error: Failed to transpile program
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems you are doing this.fingerPrint operation directly in a class, you should be doing that only inside a function. you can try moving that code block inside constructor or in ngOnInit method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code inside `constructor()` like this,

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fingerPrint: FingerprintAIO) {
      this.fingerPrint.show({
        clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',
        clientSecret: 'password', //Only necessary for Android
        disableBackup:true,  //Only for Android(optional)
        localizedFallbackTitle: 'Use Pin', //Only for iOS
        localizedReason: 'Please authenticate' //Only for iOS
      })
      .then((result: any) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After adding this I got another error but its not related to this. Anyways I am sharing it, if anyone come across same issue. 'cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT)' for '/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml'. For this what I did was ionic 'cordova platform rm android' and then' ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0'. After which when I gave 'ionic cordova build android', everything went well

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fingerPrint: FingerprintAIO) {
this.initFigerprint();
  }


initFigerprint(){

  this.fingerPrint.show({
    clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',
    clientSecret: 'password', //Only necessary for Android
    disableBackup:true,  //Only for Android(optional)
    localizedFallbackTitle: 'Use Pin', //Only for iOS
    localizedReason: 'Please authenticate' //Only for iOS
  })
  .then((result: any) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
```